# Am I able to use css (or more specifically zoom in) on mermaid flow charts in markdown somehow?

Tags: html, css, gitlab, markdown, mermaid

I've tried to use a div tag as so:  `<div style="width:300px; height:300px">` encompassing the mermaid chart's "```" quotes but nothing happens. 
I'm essentially trying to use css on the chart based on the solution to this post https://github.com/knsv/mermaid/issues/535 but I'm assuming their chart isn't implemented through markdown.

I'm also trying to do this through gitlab's wiki functionality.

Comment: First of all, you have to use colons (```:```) instead of equals signs (```=```) in the style tag: ```<div style="width:300px; height:300px">```

Comment: My bad. still doesn't change anything though.